# Where can I locate quick preview file or rather how to hide quick preview in vtiger crm 7.1.0?

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

I tried checking over the world of internet on how can I hide quick preview or edit the content of quick preview but to no luck I can't seem to find any answer nor a question about quick preview. Even I tried searching the files inside vtiger but can't seem to find any clue to where I can locate it and since there are too many files inside. Can anyone help me?

By the way I'm using Vtiger CRM 7.1.0

Answer (score 0):

After a thorough checking on the folders inside vtigercrm I was able to successfully hide quick preview though when I found out how to hide it I didn't went on searching how I can edit the content of quick preview.

This is how to do it:

1. go to /var/www/html/vtigercrm_maxicare/modules/Vtiger/views
2. and edit List.php
3. Comment out this line

   $viewer->assign('QUICK_PREVIEW_ENABLED', 'true');
4. Or you can just comment out the entire condition

   ```
   $moduleModel = Vtiger_Module_Model::getInstance($moduleName);
   if($moduleModel->isQuickPreviewEnabled()){
      $viewer->assign('QUICK_PREVIEW_ENABLED', 'true');
   }
   ```